# Cant get Expiry Headers to work

Tags: http-headers, yslow

I'm using the dreaded yslow, and having 39 static components without far-future expiration date. message kicking out at me.

I've followed a few tutorials/replies and have come up with this inside my httpdocs/.htaccess

```
#Expire Header
ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 months"
    Header append Cache-Control public
</FilesMatch>
```

However the directories that the files are all stored in are crazy for instance, i've got these  for example.

```
httpdocs/mpu/
httpdocs/css/
httpdocs/images/
httpdocs/js/
httpdocs/favicon.ico
httpdocs/mph/
httpdocs/min/
httpdocs/js/sliders/
httpdocs/js/gallery/
```

and so forth, and I'm not entirely sure if the FilesMatch expressions will capture all sub directory files or not?

If they do, then can anybody see a reason that my above snippet is still saying it has no far-future expiration date.

EDIT: This is a header response from chrome

```
Request Headers

Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11

Response Headers

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=15552000, public
Connection:close
Content-Length:3597
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Mon, 23 Jul 2012 10:49:43 GMT
Expires:Sat, 19 Jan 2013 10:49:43 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 21 Jun 2012 16:46:19 GMT
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PleskLin
```

Answer (score -1):

If you think your FilesMatch selector isn't working you can also test with the ExpiresByType directive:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
```

Looking at the headers you included, it appears for that file at least that it **is** setting the cache control properly:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=15552000, public
Date:Mon, 23 Jul 2012 10:49:43 GMT
Expires:Sat, 19 Jan 2013 10:49:43 GMT
```

The max-age parameter 15552000 is equal to 6 months, and the Expires header is today + 6 months.

Is this result for one of the files YSlow doesn't think has an expires header? Do you have a publicly-accessible link that exhibits the problem?